# generating streaming link api

Tags: api, rss

i want to know how to use google api, can anyone give some example using php.

eg. use api to get picasa album rss.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to embed the video in your html with an iframe and a url like this:

```
 <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/{videoID}/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Just change the `{videoID}` for the id of you video.

To get that code from Google, you should follow the next steps:

1. Open the video in your Drive.
2. In the top right of the view, you will see an icon that says "Pop-out", Click on it.
3. It will open the video in a new tab.
4. In the new tab click on the icon of the three dots that says "More actions" (in the top-center).
5. Select the option that says "Embed item...". You will see a popup with html code.

Comment: i don't want the embed way, just need to get the link i state above not the embed code.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no way to "predict" or "construct" a direct link to your Drive file.  The supported method of getting the link is to use the Drive API.  If you make an HTTP request to the file metadata endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}` with a valid API key, the `webContentLink` value should be the `googleusercontent.com` URL for your file.

You can try this out on the [Google API Explorer - drive.files.get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.get) to see all of the information which is available through the Drive API.

Comment: the webContent Link is: `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=xxxxxxxxx&export=download`,  i want the googleusercontent.com, which can select video quality, ending with m=37 means 1080p, ending with m=22 means 720p.

Comment: What is the `downloadUrl`?  If you follow that link (you need to be signed in to your Google account) it will redirect you to a `googleusercontent.com` link.  Does that work?